# how to search case insensitively (with '*' wildcard) with 'find'?

Tags: find

The main problem is my directory has many files with uppercase *(e.g. `Foobar.txt`, `FooBar.txt`, even `FOOBAR.txt`)*. And I find it messy to find the files by exactly typing it *(if I know the exact filenames, why would I use **`find`**?)*. So I want to type just `foobar` and want all three files in result

Also, I am using `*` both of the side of my string to match any number of characters preceding and appending in the file name.

I want an alias or function that does this.

Comment: I don't see the advantage of an function here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The correct way then would be

```
find -iname \*foobar\*
```

Where `-iname` is for case insensitive search, and the `\` to escape the `*` wildcard.

The function seems a bit unnecessary for this case, but it is easy to write

```
function lazyfind ()
{
    find -iname \*$1\*
}
```

Comment: Hey! its hard to type the escape characters everytime, do anything..

Comment: Well, for these simple tasks, I think it is better to type them again. Especially when working on multiple machines, it also annoying to copy functions for simple tasks.

Comment: @santosh, you can get the same result by using quotes: `find -iname "*foo*"`.

Comment: And using quote is more friendly if `$1` can contain spaces.

Comment: And how to do that recursively?

Comment: @SantoshKumar `find` searches recursively by default afaik.

Answer (score 0):

Should you OS is missing GNU find -iname option, here is a portable way to achieve the same:

```
cifind()
{
  pattern=""
  l=${#1}
  i=1
  while [ $i -le $l ] ; do
    lc=$(echo "$1" | cut -c $i-$i | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]')
    uc=$(echo "$lc" | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]')
    if [ ."$lc" != ."$uc" ] ; then
      pattern="${pattern}[$lc$uc]"
    else
      pattern="${pattern}$lc"
    fi
    i=$((i + 1))
  done
  find . -name "*$pattern*"
}
```

Comment: Make that `l=$(expr "x$1" : '.*')` and `[ $i -le $l ]`, in case `$1` begins with `-`. Or embrace POSIX and write `l=${#1}`, the script will be faster. Or use awk, which will be easier, less error-prone and faster.

Comment: @Gilles: For some reason, I thought ${#var} wasn't posix, thanks for the head-up. I don't think there is an issue with `[ $i -le $l ] `, however, I also corrected `$lc != $uc` to `.$lc != .$uc` to properly handle hyphens.

Comment: Arithmetic expressions (`$((…))`) are POSIX too. I meant `[ $i -lt $l ]` in my first comment, because `"x$1"` is one character longer — but using `${#1}` is clearer.